# Playframework2 - Scala, Controller-Wide Action Composition

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

In playframework 2, if you are working with Java, you can put any action composition annotation directly on the Controller class which then gets applied to all action methods defined by this controller as it is documented on the [action composition](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaActionsComposition) section in the playframework2 documentation.

```
@With(MyLogger.class)
public Admin extends Controller {
    ..
}
```

What is done with annotations in java is done with helper methods(decorators) in Scala. However in Scala, [the only examples](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaActionsComposition) on playframework2 documentation are per method.

I have a logging decorator that logs before and after each action and measures how much time it takes to execute that action. Is there any way to add this decorator to the controller so that it would be applied to each action method in the controller as in Java?

I know that I can wrap each single method with my LoggingAction:

```
def index = LoggingAction { request =>
  Ok("I have been logged")    
}
```

But this seems pretty ugly when you want to apply the logging action to all the action methods project-wide.

Comment: According to my knowledge, there is no way. You could certainly override Action with a trait, but it's the same...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's possible with action composition.
A solution might be use ScalaInterceptors by overriding onRouteRequest method.

Here is an example :

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.util.matching.Regex

// Note: this is in the default package.
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  private val controllerRoutePaths : List[Regex] =
List("""^/mycontroller/.*""".r,"""^/anOtherRegexFormycontroller/.*""".r)
  override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
     if(controllerRoutePaths.map(_.findFirstIn(request.path).isDefined).foldLeft(false)(_ || _)) {
       println("executed before every action in mycontroller:" )
       super.onRouteRequest(request)
     }
     else{
       super.onRouteRequest(request)
     }
  }

}
```